# Wampserver : localhost 403 forbidden after adding allow from all

Tags: apache

I was trying to make someone from the outside to access my localhost. I edited the httpd.conf
file by replacing

```
Allow from localhost
Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

by

```
Allow from all
```

Nothing happenned. However, when I tried to recover the old configuration, nothing works, I can't access localhost or 127.0.0.1. I get '403 forbidden'

my httpd.config:

```
DocumentRoot "c:/"
<Directory "c:/wamp/www">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    # Require all granted
    #   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Allow from localhost
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from 127.0.0.1 ::1
</Directory>
```

What can I do now ?

Comment: could you show us httpd.conf config?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share a website you can just create a virtual host listening on port 80 (default http):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www/my_web_site
  DirectoryIndex index.html

  <Directory /var/www/my_web_site>    
    AllowOverride none
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

And then from another computer inside your LAN just type your IP address.

IF you want someone outside of your LAN you should give them your public IP address and be sure you open and forward (from your router's settings) port 80 on your local IP address.

Comment: Thank you,I will try that, but now I can't even access my server locally. I've edited my question with my actual httpd.conf